# Creating a script that cleans RAM upon locking the screen

Tags: boot, ram

I own an android with cyanogen mod installed and would like to add a script, that cleans the RAM automatically each time i lock my screen.
I seek to achieve that remains of the encryption key are getting overwritten in order to prevent a boot attack.
Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en). In older version (Not sure about last update) you could select an option to clear RAM when screen was turned off.